# WPF slowdown performance

Tags: wpf, performance, optimization, slowdown

It is an application developed in VS2010 with the philosophy of 3 layers for WPF Web Browser against Postgres database. A level of code (VB.NET) have followed the best practices suggested by Microsoft for code optimization.

This is an application of high "traffic" as it allows a number of users that call "transcriptionists" to perform continuous data processing on large amounts of data.

That is, is an application that allows a number of users (n) the "attack" certain amount of data continuously, using IE9 them (or use Firefox with a complement that allows visualization of XBAP.

Many users have reported that initially the application starts well in performance and fluidity, but after half an hour (Windows XP Professional) and hour and a half almost two hours (Windows 7) the application starts to drop their speed of response, forcing the user to close the browser and on occasion to reboot.

The teams are varied in S.O. (Windows 7 and Windows XP Professional), some with 2 or 3 gb memory and with various processors from Pentium to Intel Core i3.

Now, the question

How I can improve application performance on a stage so varied?

Why does the application starts well and gradually begins to fall in performance opportunities to collapse with an error?

Are there any free or paid software to help me identify certain points where the application may be collapsing?

In advance, thank you all for your feedback.

Comment: This sounds like a memory leak or very high allocation causing GC pressure.

Comment: Is this silverlight or WPF?

Comment: Just WPF Web Browser Style.....

Comment: Something I forgot to comment: This application stores several things in memory (sometimes large data amount) depending on functions and user profile to minimize the impact to database.

Perhaps this balance is not as "balanced" because the application has additional logic to lighten the weight and database traffic.

Furthermore, both the application server and the database are different teams .... as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have a memory leak. We use this profiler from SciTech and it is very nice.

[.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/)

Comment: Download the application and just start running with VS2010 Professional, the program. NET Profiler gives an error jejejej a bit ironic thing ....

I sent the log report incidents and Sci-tech ....

Comment: We use it with VS2010 pro, gotta be something that's fixable